# Getting 'f1fa' from ion ios icons

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome, glyphicons

I am using ion ios icons on my index page. Well I was until I made some large changes regarding page speed. Well I tried to revert back but it is too far back. I can't believe I forgot to check this seemed like a non issue, never thought of it.

So my issue I am actually getting is that the icons are showing up as the text `f3ce` and `f472` ect. I searched online and found nothing. I would include code but I am not sure what to include. My whole header file? What idk?

Suggestions to try?

Comment: Please show your codes. Have you included the CSS of ionicons ?

Comment: What exact code should I post? I said in my OP that I did not know what exact code to include and I am not including the private repo.

Comment: Obviously the HTML code.

Comment: I solved it and the HTML code had ZERO to do with it so would have been a waste to post it. Issue was that the CSS when put into one file to limit css loads caused some unknown issue. Keeping it separate solved it.